# can't get logo to display in navbar html

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am making a simple app, and I can't get a logo to appear in my navbar.  It is located in the same folder as my component, and its name is "logo.jpg".  Can someone please help.  I have been fiddling with it for some time now and am unable to get the logo to display.  Thanks!

Here is the code for my component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Navbar, Nav,NavDropdown, Form, FormControl, Button} from 'react-bootstrap';

import './Topbar.css'

class Topbar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <div class="topnav">
        <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
      <div class="logo-image">
            <img src="logo" alt ="a" class="img-fluid"/>
      </div>
      </a>

        <a href="#news">News</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
      </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Topbar;

//and my css

.topnav {
  background-color: #FFFF00;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #808080;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.logo-image{
    width: 46px;
    height: 46px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: -6px;
}
```

Thanks! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For development purposes, just import the image from the current location with a relative path and then use the url provided in the variable `img` and set the `src` of the image tag with it.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Navbar, Nav,NavDropdown, Form, FormControl, Button} from 'react-bootstrap';

import img from './logo.png'
import './Topbar.css'

class Topbar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <div class="topnav">
        <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
      <div class="logo-image">
            <img src={img} alt ="a" class="img-fluid"/>
      </div>
      </a>

        <a href="#news">News</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
      </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert the logo‘s path into the src attribute like e.g. `<img src="/logo.jpg" alt ="a" class="img-fluid"/>`

Note that the logo path is relative to the location of the underlying file.

Comment: I have it saved in the exact same folder and my entire line is: "  <img src="logo.png" alt ="a" class="img-fluid"/>.  Can't figure out why this isn't working.

Comment: You said it is .jpg so why do you call it logo.png?

Comment: I actually changed it to png.  The exact file is "logo.png".  It's in the same directory and it's not working

Comment: And I also tried to display another image somewhere else and I'm getting the exact same problem.

Comment: What does the ˋSourceˋ of your Developer tools say?

Comment: How do I check this.  I am in developer tools and have clicked on sources but I'm not sure what to look for?

Comment: There should be the Image.png file loaded by your browser. If not, something is wrong with the path

Comment: Ok, thanks for helping!  I'll try and figure it out.